# How do you prompt for an Active Directory user name or group with Wix installer?

Tags: active-directory, wix

My WiX installer is creating an event log source, and the customer is insisting that they want to set the access to the event source via the installer. That is, when the run the installer, they want to be able to select an Active Directory user or group with the Windows user picker. Then the installer is to use that value to set access permissions.

How do I go about showing a user picker with WiX UI? Is there in fact such a feature already in Wix-UI? If not, how would I go about writing an extension for this purpose?